# Drag and drop images over an image to fill the missing parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, frontend

I'm a beginner in front end development, trying to make a project of my own, where I'm to drag and drop image on to an image to fill the missing parts in an image. I've tried this using an image map in HTML and tried using the HTML5 drag and drop functionality. But seems like we can only drop on to a div not on to the area in an image map. It would also be nice, if the area is highlighted when an image will be dropped. It would be a great start for me if someone can point me to a ui plugin that I can use or some resources for starting this.

Comment: You should drop that HTML5 and use [jQuery (ui)](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by JavaSpyder, jQuery UI seems like a good plugin to use for this over the HTML5 functionality. You can easily give DOM elements drag/drop capabilities with a minimal amount of code.

Your code might look something like this:

```
$( function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    // target image and do stuff with it
  }
});
} );
```

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

https://jqueryui.com/droppable/